# How to stop incremental build of Visual Studio permanently?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, incremental-build

I know about the property `/incremental` but it need to changed every time `NO` if I want to stop incremental build. Is there any way to stop it for all the projects permanently.

Comment: It is a linker option.  Usually the very last thing done in a build so hard to guess what the question could be about.  Forcing it to NO while the project is building certainly makes little sense.  Describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens.  Change the MSBuild verbosity and show the trace it generates.

Comment: The configuration setting in the project properties does not take effect? When you disable the Incremental Build setting it should be work forever in that project.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri yes forever that project... how to make it forever for that ide?

Comment: @pcbabu usually new projects are based on templates. I were you I'll do a research on this. It may exist a template that can be edited and force the setting Off from scratch.

Comment: @Mauro you are in exact point. But in cpp project I have only option. I was guiding few student writing their first code. But 2012 may not for beginners and they always face problem here. Thats why I posted here and started bounty. But problem not solved.

Comment: @pcbabu I did a research and edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set this from `Incremental Property` in `Linker` Properties Folder.

Go to: `properties page->Linker Folder` and from there modify `Incremental Linking` Property.

this is is a detailed  [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Well @apomene gives the details for C++.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691231%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are for C#

EDIT:

Doing a deeper research I scanned all files inside `$(UserRootDir)` and Visual Studio folder looking for the `LinkIncremental` tag, used by `MSBuild` to specify to do (or not) the incremental linking, but I don't find anything.

For the other side, inside many dll used by project wizards, they refer to the `LinkIncremental` tag and assume they finish setting up the project when one is created.

My conclusion is that you can develop a Visual Studio plugin and attach to some event when a project is created to set the [VCLinkerTool.LinkIncremental](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.linkincremental.aspx) to false.